# Comparison of forbidden symbols and names in different FS's

Tags: filesystems, filenames

What symbols and (maybe) names are forbidden on different files systems available in modern Linux distribution?

Comment: Maybe interesting in this context: [Understanding Unix file name encoding](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/39175/12779)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limiting factor is more the OS than the FS.  For example, the only forbidden character in ext4 is `'\0'` (NULL), which is also forbidden in unix, but unix and linux have one other forbidden character, `'/'`.

Answer (score 1):

On Unix, a file name can contain any character except '\0' (NUL) and '/' (directory separator). All current Linux/Unix native filessytems have to handle this. Foreign filesystems might have their own restrictions (for example, MS-DOS FAT can have only filenames in the 8+3 format, with exactly one '.', probably ':' and '\' are forbidden too; VFAT presumabably forbids ':' and '\' only).